# d3 Improperly parsing time from timestamp

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with d3 to plot values over time, I have a timestamp in the format of `2021-07-01 05:00:00`

I am trying to use `d3.timeParse` with the following code:

```
d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%I:%S")("2021-07-01 05:00:00")
```

which returns

```
Thu Jul 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

so it thinks that it parses successfully but if you notice it doesn't parse the hour correctly, however, if I change the minute to this `2021-07-01 05:15:00` it returns

```
Thu Jul 01 2021 15:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

I don't understand why the minute position is being parsed as the hour and the hour is being ignored. I have tested this all in the console.

Comment: H and I both represent hours (24 hour vs 12 hour respectively). You probably want %H:%M

Comment: @AndrewReid omg, yep, that was it, thank you. if you leave that as an answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are parsing the hour twice: both H and I represent hours (24 hour and 12 hour representations respectively). This likely means you are overwriting the first hour parsed with the second hour, hence your results : the minute position is being parsed as the hour and the hour is being ignored.

You are likely looking for %H:%M for hours and minutes instead.